# HTTPS URLs for photos

Tags: ssl, https, facebook-fql, photo

All photo URLs in the FQL photo table are HTTP-URLs and not HTTPS-URLs. It's not possible to rewrite the URL with https instead of http. How do I do to get the HTTPS-URLs instead?

### Why:

Internet Explorer is warning users with a pop-up when they load a HTTPS page which includes objects with HTTP-URLs. Since Facebook requires apps to have HTTPS support and since Facebook supports Internet Explorer fully (I guess but I'm actually not sure about this), there should be a way to get HTTPS-URLs to photos.

### Example FQL query:

SELECT pid, src_small FROM photo WHERE pid IN ('xxx');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API call, add a `return_ssl_resources=1` parameter, which will cause the image URLs to come back as HTTPS URLs

Comment: Great! The return_ssl_resources parameter is only mentioned in one page in the documentation and that is not the how-to-enable-https-guide.

Comment: Noted, I'll get it added there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
`$params = array(
    'return_ssl_resources'=>1,
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' => "SELECT pid, src_small FROM photo WHERE pid IN ('xxx')",
);
$result = $facebook->api($params);`
```